Convert a protein alignment to a table in R
I have a protein alignment (CLUSTAL format) that looks as in this link
(also image attached) and would like to input into R and create a table that has

position in SMARCE1
residue in SMARCE1
position in swsn-3_protein
residue in swns-3_protein and
the corresponding ., * or :

Looks like:
Row 1   1  M _ _ N/A

Row36   36 Y 1 M N/A

Row37   37 N 2 S  .

Row38   38 N 3 S  .

Row39   39 Y 4 F  :

I can read in this alignment file as per the read.alignment function from seqinrhttps://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/seqinr/versions/4.2-36/topics/read.alignment.
fasta.res <- read.alignment(file = "sample.fasta", format="fasta", whole.header =TRUE)
clustal.res <- read.alignment(file ="sample.aln", format="clustal")

I get for clustal.res:
structure(list(nb = 2, nam = c("SMARCE1", "swsn-3"), seq = list(
    "mskrpsyappptpapatqmpstpgfvgynpyshlaynnyrlg-gnpgtnsrvtassgiti\t59pkppkppdkplmpymrysrkvwdqvkasnpdlklweigkiiggmwrdltdeekqeylney\t119eaekieynesmkayhnspaylayinaksraeaaleeesrqrqsrmekgepymsiqpaedp\t179ddyddgfsmkhtatarfqrnhrliseilsesvvpdvrsvvttarmqvlkrqvqslmvhqr\t239kleaellqieerhqekkrkflestdsfnnelkrlcglkvevdmekiaaeiaqaeeqarkr\t299qeereke-------aaeqaersqssivpeeeqaankgeekkddenipmeteethleette\t352sqqngeegtstpedkesgqegvdsmaeegtsdsntgsesnsatveepptdpipedekke\t\t411", 
    "-----------------------------------mssfrhpqatparn------fqdms\t19srgpkvperplqpymrysrkmwpkvraenpeaqlwdigkmigkywldlpdgekshyqhey\t79elekadyekqmkhfqgngisnfmink-grak----nnekmsrsrmdaggv--viqpv-de\t131ddggnelstrrlagvrfernnrlisdlfspsivtdtrtvvphhrmemlkrqatslgthqs\t191kleeeltklerahdnrkraiekgsddfqeqlkkavsekpvvdeekfeetvkeweeklata\t251yeeykkkqettatqnansapll-rnlvmeetpktpeqekeqnvkekpaestetp------\t304------------------aagtepstddgaiettttt--tttenkekpeekmee-----\t\t338"), 
    com = NA), class = "alignment")
And for fasta.res:structure(list(nb = 2, nam = c("SMARCE1", "swsn-3"), seq = list(
    "mskrpsyappptpapatqmpstpgfvgynpyshlaynnyrlg-gnpgtnsrvtassgitipkppkppdkplmpymrysrkvwdqvkasnpdlklweigkiiggmwrdltdeekqeylneyeaekieynesmkayhnspaylayinaksraeaaleeesrqrqsrmekgepymsiqpaedpddyddgfsmkhtatarfqrnhrliseilsesvvpdvrsvvttarmqvlkrqvqslmvhqrkleaellqieerhqekkrkflestdsfnnelkrlcglkvevdmekiaaeiaqaeeqarkrqeereke-------aaeqaersqssivpeeeqaankgeekkddenipmeteethleettesqqngeegtstpedkesgqegvdsmaeegtsdsntgsesnsatveepptdpipedekke", 
    "-----------------------------------mssfrhpqatparn------fqdmssrgpkvperplqpymrysrkmwpkvraenpeaqlwdigkmigkywldlpdgekshyqheyelekadyekqmkhfqgngisnfmink-grak----nnekmsrsrmdaggv--viqpv-deddggnelstrrlagvrfernnrlisdlfspsivtdtrtvvphhrmemlkrqatslgthqskleeeltklerahdnrkraiekgsddfqeqlkkavsekpvvdeekfeetvkeweeklatayeeykkkqettatqnansapll-rnlvmeetpktpeqekeqnvkekpaestetp------------------------aagtepstddgaiettttt--tttenkekpeekmee-----"), 
    com = NA), class = "alignment")

It has the sequence names and the residues. Not sure if the alignment is read in and trying to figure out how to get to the table I need from here.

This type of domain-specific question is better suited to https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/

Here is my approach to create the dataframe from CLUSTAL output.
library(readr)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)


# Read each line as string then remove empty lines, skip header
clustal_raw <- read_lines("sample.aln", skip = 1)
clustal_raw <- clustal_raw[clustal_raw != ""]

# The trailing positions are separted from the sequences with tab in the example.
# The delim could also be space. Remove those
clustal_raw <- str_remove(clustal_raw, "(\t| )[:digit:]+")

# The remaining part is a fix width structure
# Add id to the symbol lines
str_sub(clustal_raw[str_starts(clustal_raw, "      ")], 1, 3) <- "symbol"

# Identify the position of the last space
last_space <- str_locate(clustal_raw, " +")[1, "end"]

# Read fixed width lines into dataframe
clustal_df <- read_fwf(I(clustal_raw), 
                       fwf_cols(id = c(1, last_space), seq = c(last_space + 1, nchar(clustal_raw[1]))),
                       trim_ws = FALSE) %>%
  mutate(id = str_remove_all(id, " ")) %>%
  # Collapse sequences for each id
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarize(seq = paste0(seq, collapse = ""),
            .groups = "drop")

# Get the squence names
seq_names <- clustal_df$id[1:(nrow(clustal_df) - 1)]

# Convert to vector
clustal_vec <- clustal_df$seq
names(clustal_vec) <- clustal_df$id

# Split vector by charachters, and convert to dataframe
output <- str_split(clustal_vec, pattern = "", simplify = TRUE) %>%
  t() %>%
  as.data.frame() 
names(output) <- names(clustal_vec)

# This function takes a broken down sequence and return the position for 
# each residue. Gaps return NAs.
GetPosition <- function(vec) {
  # mark non-gap positions
  vec_bool <- vec != "-"
  # residue position +1 if for non-gap
  vec_out <- cumsum(vec_bool)
  vec_out[vec_bool == FALSE] <- NA
  return(vec_out)
}

output <- output %>%
  # Get the residue positions for each sequence
  mutate(across(all_of(seq_names), GetPosition, .names = "{.col}_POS")) %>%
  # Rearrange the column orders
  relocate(ends_with("POS")) %>%
  relocate(starts_with(seq_names)) %>%
  # Replace space as NA in the symbol column.
  mutate(symbol = ifelse(symbol == " ",
                         NA,
                         symbol))

slice(output, c(1, 36:39))

The output look like this:
  SMARCE1_POS SMARCE1 swsn-3_protein_POS swsn-3_protein symbol
1           1       M                 NA              -   <NA>
2          36       Y                  1              M   <NA>
3          37       N                  2              S      .
4          38       N                  3              S      .
5          39       Y                  4              F      :

